# How do I perform ios "open with" from python code?

Tags: python, ios, x-callback-url

With Pythonista I can easily produce a file which will be saved in the Pythonista file system. If it has the appropriate file ending, in this case ".gpx", accessing that file will call up the ios dialog "open with" and a list of possible apps.

Is it possible, using the x-callback-url system, to open the ios app (in this case gaiagps://) with the above file directly from the python code, saving the extra step of clicking on the file?

This line is surely close:

```
webbrowser.open('gaiagps://demofile.gpx?action=run')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard python console.open_in(file_path) is the best solution possible.